# problems loading data into the database

Tags: php, mysql, redbean

Good day to all
Trying to complete an order to create an online store
But before me was the problem of not entering data into the database
In this order I use an ORM such as RedBeamPHP
When you click on the button, the order status should change from new to processed
I would be grateful for any help

this is my OrderController.php

```
public function viewAction(){
        $order_id = $this->getRequestID();
        $order = \R::getRow("SELECT `order`.*, `user`.`name`, ROUND(SUM(`order_product`.`price`), 2) AS `sum` FROM `order`
  JOIN `user` ON `order`.`user_id` = `user`.`id`
  JOIN `order_product` ON `order`.`id` = `order_product`.`order_id`
  WHERE `order`.`id` = ?
  GROUP BY `order`.`id` ORDER BY `order`.`status`, `order`.`id` LIMIT 1", [$order_id]);
        if(!$order){
            throw new \Exception('Страница не найдена', 404);
        }
        $order_products = \R::findAll('order_product', "order_id = ?", [$order_id]);
        $this->setMeta("Заказ №{$order_id}");
        $this->set(compact('order', 'order_products'));
    }

    public function changeAction(){
        $order_id = $this->getRequestID();
        $status = !empty($_GET['status']) ? '1' : '0';
        $order = \R::load('order', $order_id);
        if(!$order){
            throw new \Exception('Страница не найдена', 404);
        }
        $orders->status = $status;
        $orders->update_at = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        \R::store($order);
        $_SESSION['success'] = 'Изменения сохранены';
        redirect();
    }



<section class="content-header">
    <h1>
        Заказ №<?=$order['id'];?>
        <?php if(!$order['status']): ?>
            <a href="<?=ADMIN;?>/order/change?id=<?=$order['id'];?>&status=1" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Одобрить</a>
        <?php else: ?>
            <a href="<?=ADMIN;?>/order/change?id=<?=$order['id'];?>&status=0" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Вернуть на доработку</a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <a href="<?=ADMIN;?>/order/delete?id=<?=$order['id'];?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete">Удалить</a>
    </h1>
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="<?=ADMIN;?>"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Главная</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?=ADMIN;?>/order">Список заказов</a></li>
        <li class="active">Заказ №<?=$order['id'];?></li>
    </ol>
</section>
<section class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Номер заказа</td>
                                    <td><?=$order['id'];?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Дата заказа</td>
                                    <td><?=$order['date'];?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Дата изменения</td>
                                    <td><?=$order['update_at'];?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Кол-во позиций в заказе</td>
                                    <td><?=count($order_products);?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Сумма заказа</td>
                                    <td><?=$order['sum'];?> <?=$order['currency'];?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Имя заказчика</td>
                                    <td><?=$order['name'];?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Статус</td>
                                    <td><?=$order['status'];?></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Комментарий</td>
                                    <td><?=$order['note'];?></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <h3>Детали заказа</h3>
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Наименование</th>
                                <th>Кол-во</th>
                                <th>Цена</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <?php $qty = 0; foreach($order_products as $product): ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?=$product->id;?></td>
                                    <td><?=$product->title;?></td>
                                    <td><?=$product->qty; $qty += $product->qty?></td>
                                    <td><?=$product->price;?></td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                                <tr class="active">
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <b>Итого:</b>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><b><?=$qty;?></b></td>
                                    <td><b><?=$order['sum'];?> <?=$order['currency'];?></b></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Your updating `$orders`, it should be `$order`

Comment: I don’t know how but when I copy code here I m have mistake. In my project file I’m have $order

Comment: these lines `$orders->status = $status;
        $orders->update_at = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");`